Confusion about sound intensity
I think there is something fundamental I'm not understanding about sound intensity.
I have a small speaker at home, roughly 10cm square and the specs state it has 3 W output. That equates to 300 W/m^2 output intensity.
But this is an insane output and I must be misunderstanding something important as it is far higher than 200 dB.
Am I misunderstanding the 3W output or am I wrong in calculating the intensity?

is it actually power output? I am also puzzled. Also, usually speakers don't give max power output like that. Would you please tell me how you calculated 200 dB? I found it 140 dB considering threshold intensity 10^-12W/m^2.

3W is the power it consumes not the power it radiates as sound. The vast majority of the power ends up as heat not sound.

@JohnRennie I felt that too. No speaker gives max output.

If you've got an aperture with 1/100 m^2 area, and you've got 3W coming through the aperture (but probably you have less, according to comments above), then what's "insane" about saying it's 300W/m^2?

@Ritzthephysibeast I calculated the db as 10*log(300W/m^2  / 10^-12 W/m^2) = 333 dB.
And from the table on wikipedia the eruption from Krakatoa was around 170dB this was why it was insane to me.

@Theo I get it. You misunderstood it as output power.

The marking on the speaker is supposed to show maximum input power. As often with technical specifications on items aimed at consumers they can be, well, a bit shady.
A smaller speaker with a 3W input could probably output around 85dB SPL measured at one meter from about 150 Hz and up to maybe 10kHz. Outside that range the volume is lower. Only a small portion of the input power is transferred into actual sound, the rest turns into heat.

Ok, so I was misunderstanding the actual specifications. Thank you.

Theo, It is actually electric power input, but not max sound output. Also, 140 dB speaker would be illegal, as you would kill people with sound while aeroplane is about 120 dB. I hope you don't want to do that. :)
Btw, the power output would not be 170 dB but 140 dB, considering threshold frequency, 10^-12 W/m^2. It would not be as loud as Krakatoa.
The speaker while charging takes 3J electric current per second. Don't confuse it with sound. Thanks.
Please upvote if it helps.
